# Electron volts with boost::units?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-units

Does boost::units have an option to express energy in electron volts (eV)? I can't seem to find the right header file for that

Comment: It doesn't exist yet. Some are floating around the web though

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but you can get it so:

```
boost::units::quantity<boost::units::si::energy> electronvolt 
   = 1. * boost::units::si::volt * boost::units::si::constants::codata::e;
```

(however, this is not what the user was asking: no, Boost.Units has no support for electronvolt)